# <a> Tags Appearing In My DIV's

Tags: html, css, asp.net

I have a serious problem :( I am making a profile page and my DIV's are always clickable(This should not happen), when I inspect element it on chrome, it shows a bunch of  on all DIVS... I did not write these codes here are sample

Code on Visual Studio

```
<div style="width: 1179px; height: 100px;">
        <div style="width: 350px; height: 100px; float:left; margin-right: 64.5px; background-color: pink; border-radius: 5px;">
            <img src="../Resources/Referrals-Icon.png" height="100" style="float: left;" />
            <p>Referrals</p>
            <p><%=ReferralsCount%></p>
        </div>
        <div style="width: 350px; height: 100px; float:left; background-color: green; border-radius: 5px;">
            <p>Blessing Points</p>
            <p><%=BlessingPoints%></p>
        </div>
        <div style="width: 350px; height: 100px; float:left; margin-left: 64.5px; background-color: grey; border-radius: 5px;">
            <p>Support</p>
            <a href="#">FAQ</a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Code on Browser

```
<div style="width: 1179px; height: 100px;"><a href="Profile.aspx">
        <div style="width: 350px; height: 100px; float:left; margin-right: 64.5px; background-color: pink; border-radius: 5px;">
            <img src="../Resources/Referrals-Icon.png" height="100" style="float: left;">
            <p>Referrals</p>
            <p>0</p>
        </div>
        <div style="width: 350px; height: 100px; float:left; background-color: green; border-radius: 5px;">
            <p>Blessing Points</p>
            <p>0</p>
        </div>
        </a><div style="width: 350px; height: 100px; float:left; margin-left: 64.5px; background-color: grey; border-radius: 5px;"><a href="Profile.aspx">
            <p>Support</p>
            </a><a href="#">FAQ</a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I tried searching all around my codes :( and all my CSS but I do not know what this is :(

This is the current design(no problem in design but the divs being clickable bugs me a lot and the anonymous  tags are really irritating)
[image: Current Design]

Comment: its all ok here in visual studio... this is the first time i encountered this..

Comment: there must be something in the codebehind that buts the <a> tag in there

Comment: i tried checking all .CS files but nothing :( actually they are all on default.. i havent written anything there except  public int ReferralsCount;
    public float BlessingPoints; all pages in the folder produce that <a> tag :( but all other pages from different area dont :(

Comment: any javascript running in on the page that could have added it?

Comment: nope... not yet... im still in the phase of making the layout of the page :) no jquery either or bootstrap.. last thing i edited was a bunch of css to make a accordion menu on the left side of page

Comment: are you having profiles on the site? I think that is what adding the link since you use profile variables within the divs.

Comment: what is the width of the image Referrals-Icon.png ? can you please post an image of what you are trying to accomplish..

Comment: i tried removing the <%%> variables and still generating <a> tags.. i will post the picture of the current design/layout nothing wrong with design... but there all DIV/BOX and image are suddenly became clickable ,,

Comment: the Referrals-Icon.png is 100x100

Comment: Some where in your aspx page you have `<a href="Profile.aspx">` it looks like you have not closed that tag and Chrome is taking it's best bet at closing it for you. Have you got this code from "View Source" or from Inspecting using Developer Tools? Their is a big difference between the two.

Comment: Thank You! That Did The Trick! i forgot to close the code :) on the left accordion <li><a href="Profile.aspx">Profile</li> hehehehe thanks :) please post that as answer and i will mark it :) incase anyone else has the problem :)

Comment: On a side note I hope you're not planning on keeping the inline styles. They are bad practice and makes code harder to debug.

Comment: @JonP what would you suggest? :) can you give me something about good practice of not using inline styles? :) sorry for bad english

Comment: http://webdesign.about.com/od/css/a/aa073106.htm & http://robertnyman.com/2008/11/20/why-inline-css-and-javascript-code-is-such-a-bad-thing/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some where in your aspx page you have `<a href="Profile.aspx">` it looks like you have not closed that tag and Chrome is taking it's best bet at closing it for you.